# Encerrar timer com um alert

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho esse timer de 10 segundos em JS.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {

  var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;

  setInterval(function(){
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 10, 10);
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }

  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var duration = 3600 * 2; // Conversao para horas
  var display = document.querySelector("#timer"); // Exibir o timer

  startTimer(duration, display);
}
```

Que chama este campo para começar a contagem.

```html
<div class="fixed-top" id="timer" align="center"></div>
```

**Eu queria que, quando ele zerar exibir um alerta informando que o tempo acabou!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito mais simples é adicionar uma verificação para saber quando o tempo acabou, assim:

```
setInterval(function(){
  // ...
  if (seconds == 0) {
    alert('tempo acabou!');
  }
}, 1000);
```